# Virtuoso OWL 2 DL Reasoning

Tags: rdf, jena, owl, virtuoso, pellet

I have a Virtuoso server 7.20.3217 where I upload my data. According to Virtuoso documentation, Virtuoso supports basic owl reasoning such as *rdfs:subClassOf* or *rdfs:subPropertyOf*.

What should I do in order to enable OWL 2 DL reasoning? Or even support SWRL rules? Is there any chance of incorporating this capabilities to Virtuoso? For example by incorporating an external reasoner like Pellet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Virtuoso 7.x does not support SWRL nor fully support OWL 2 DL (though [it can be made to support a subset of OWL predicates](http://vos.openlinksw.com/owiki/wiki/VOS/VirtTipsAndTricksGuideRDFSchemaOWLInferenceRules)).  (Also see [1](http://vos.openlinksw.com/owiki/wiki/VOS/VirtsubClassOfOrientedSubsumptionTransitiveOptions), [2](http://vos.openlinksw.com/owiki/wiki/VOS/VirtTipsAndTricksUnderstandingRelationshipSemantics).)

Virtuoso 8.x implements SPIN, into which SWRL can be translated, and the same subset of OWL predicates, among other more complex reasoning.

See [Creating Custom Inference Rules using the SPIN Vocabulary and Virtuoso 8.0](http://%20%20%20%20https://medium.com/virtuoso-blog/virtuoso-8-0-creating-a-custom-inference-rules-using-spin-vocabulary-d7a060f859ef) and [SWRL and Virtuoso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28468426/swrl-and-virtuoso), for starters.

User documentation is in progress; you can get assistance via the [Virtuoso Users mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/virtuoso-users/) or the [OpenLink Support Case System](http://support.openlinksw.com/support/online-support.vsp).

Comment: And yet some of the DL reasoning is possible in Virtuoso, and that includes `rdfs:subClassOf` and [transitivity](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/virtuosofaq6/). And the what does `define input:inference` actually do?

Comment: "[In a SPARQL query, the `define input:inference` clause is used to instruct the compiler to use the rules in the named rule set.](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/rdfsparqlruleenableinfr/#rdfsparqlruleenableinfr)"  Also [this](http://vos.openlinksw.com/owiki/wiki/VOS/VirtSpongerLinkedDataHooksIntoSPARQL#INPUT%20Pragmas).

Comment: @IvoVelitchkov The reasoning in Virtuoso does'nt work on classExpression and propertyExpression. This is an huge part of the DL reasoning that can be use use rdfs:subClassOf, a part that could be game changing.

Answer (score 1):

To provide some important clarity to this matter regarding Virtuoso and Inference Rules, I would like to add the following:

Virtuoso offers a number of built-in inference rules based on entity relationship type semantics described in both the RDF Schema (rdfs:subClassOf and rdfs:subPropertyOf) and OWL Ontologies (owl:sameAs, owl:inverseOf, owl:inverseFunctionalProperty, owl:equivalentClass, owl:equivalentProperty, and owl:SymmetricProperty).

Starting with version 8.1 it also includes the creation of Custom Inference Rules using SPARQL CONSTRUCT as the Rules Langauge, courtesy of terms from the SPIN Ontology.

Thus, if you want additional relationship type semantics informing desired reasoning and inference e.g., as per OWL DL or anything else, all you have to do is create a custom inference rule.

Links

1. [Detailed post about Virtuoso Reasoning and Inference Capabilities](https://medium.com/virtuoso-blog/magic-sets-and-custom-inference-rules-in-virtuoso-8-x-db783f8d98d2)

I hope this clarifies this important issue?